# Does scalar types include pointers of class types?

Tags: c++, types

Scalar types as we know are: `int, char, float,` etc. But pointers are also scalar types. Does it include pointers to a class type or only a scalar type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A scalar type is the type of an object that only contains a single item. A pointer would fit that description, even if it points to a class object.

The opposite of a scalar would be things like an array or a struct.

Answer (score 3):

Any pointer type is a scalar type (as is any arithmetic, enumeration or pointer-to-member type). Loosely speaking, a scalar type is a type that describes a single object (a pointer  also being classified as an object).